# Issue with yarn e npm

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, yarnpkg, aws-codeartifact

Good morning, yesterday I was trying to deploy an application of mine through aws ... However today when I went back to my dev course, when executing a yarn add or npm install the following error appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzV5T.png)

"crinet/crinet-repo-2" was a repository that I created in code artifacts, in an attempt to deploy ... Could you help me to reverse this?

Answer (score 1):

The authentical token has expired. Please reauthenticate using the command:

```
$ aws codeartifact login --tool npm --repository <repository_name> --domain <domain_name> --domain-owner <aws_account_number>
```

This command writes to ~/.npmrc

> CodeArtifact authorization tokens that are created from the login command are valid for a period of 12 hours, so you must call login periodically to refresh the token. The 12-hour authorization period begins after login is called.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/npm-auth.html